Varchar to Date in SSIS
I'm trying to convert a varchar date in the format 2023-01-02T00:00 to DT_DBTIMESTAMP in SSIS. Currently, I’m using this expression in a Derived Column Transformation:
(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)(SUBSTRING([start_at], 1, 4) + "-" + SUBSTRING([start_at], 6, 2) + "-" + SUBSTRING([start_at], 9, 2) + " " + SUBSTRING([start_at], 12, 5) + ":00")
This works fine, but it fails when encountering NULL values. To handle NULLs, I tried modifying the expression as follows:
ISNULL([start_at]) ? NULL(DT_DBTIMESTAMP) : (DT_DBTIMESTAMP)(SUBSTRING([start_at], 1, 4) + "-" + SUBSTRING([start_at], 6, 2) + "-" + SUBSTRING([start_at], 9, 2) + " " + SUBSTRING([start_at], 12, 5) + ":00")
However, this expression isn’t working as expected. Any suggestions on handling NULL values in this conversion?

Why convert in in SSIS? If the value is coming from SQL Server, why not convert it there? Better yet, why not store the value as a date and time value to start with?

The data originates from an external system using a 3rd-party integration tool, and I am currently designing an ETL pipeline to handle the flow through RAW, STG, DIM, and FCT layers.

"However, this expression isn’t working as expected" Can you elaborate; not as expected doesn't help us understand the problem.

I want the expression to pass NULL values as NULL to the destination and convert existing varchar values to timestamp format where applicable.
But I am getting these errors.
[Derived Column [2]] Error: The conditional operation failed.
[Derived Column [2]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Derived Column" failed because error code 0xC0049063 occurred, and the error row disposition on "Derived Column.Outputs[Derived Column Output].

Personally, I would recommend using a dbtimestamp2, which maps to datetime2. Converting your string to that is significantly easier; replace the T with a space and then add the seconds on:
(DT_DBTIMESTAMP2,0) (REPLACE(DateString,"T"," ") + ":00")

DateString in this case if your column containing your (W)STR date formatted in the style yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm.
There's no need to handle the NULL values explicitly either, as a NULL will result in NULL, as can be seen in the below screenshot of the Data Viewer:


Thanks a lot for the solution. Now it make sense to me. The error I am getting is not because of the NULL Values. It's because of the bad nature of the data I am getting. In the column, I have two kinds of String Date 2023-01-02T00:00:00Z and +292278994-08-17T08:12:55Z.
So my given expression was getting failed here. Is there any solution to convert both the string date to datetime2 in a single expression?

Sounds like the problem is your source data, @MeetBardoliya . "+292278994-08-17" is clearly not a date (or maybe it is, but we'll long be dead by the time we reach it as that's over 290M years away), and you have some significant data issues at the source.

Got it. Thanks a lot. I really appreciate it.

@MeetBardoliya you might consider including a sanitation step before adding derived column. You could use TRY_CONVERT, like TRY_CONVERT(date, MyMaybeBogusDateString) which returns null if the data is bogus like '+292278994-08-17T08:12:55Z'. Maybe clear that data out of the source where it's bogus like that, or maybe use ISNULL in your expression on the derived column.
